# Multiple controls with same ToolStripMenuItem's ShortcutKeys

Tags: c#, winforms, menuitem

I have two `UserControls`, both containing `ToolStripMenuItem` with `ShortcutKeys` set to the same value.

When I add them to a form

```
this.Controls.Add(new UserControl1());
this.Controls.Add(new UserControl2());
```

It doesn't matter which control I have focused. If I use shortcut then first created control's menu item action is called.

Is it possible to change shortcut receiver object depending on controls focus?

Comment: In other words you have 2 main menus or what? I'd like to see a screenshot.

Comment: Something like that. I'm not sure if they can be called "main", because they belong to controls

Comment: This is why I want to have a look at it, to criticize the idea and think about an alternative. What you want to do is ... unusual. Typical window has just one main menu. To have many you can use MDI, where children are `Form`s, not `UserControl` and active child window menu intercept hotkeys.

Comment: This solution is raised because I don't want to have modules in single windows but all in one. So I changed my forms to controls